# Features installed with profile are overridden

Tags: 7, users, workbench

We are using workbench with the subpermissions module.  We have created two features which set custom permissions for workbench and for subpermissions.  If we install the workbench feature and then the subpermissions feature, both features show as Default and not overwritten.  If we install these two features last with a profile, both features show as overridden and the permissions are not correctly set. 
Any idea why this is happening and how would we investigate?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently things in a profile info file are loaded before things in a profile install file.  I moved the two features from the info file into the install file and put them last.  After a new site install, the features were not overridden and worked as expected.